# Server 2012 R2 Installed AD DC and Lost Internet Access

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, dhcp-server, 1and1

I am a developer and new to set up and server config... so please forgive my full lack of understanding. I am using a 1&1 Cloud Server with Server 2012 R2 Standard and am trying to set it as an AD DC for a new forest.

My lack of understanding comes into play with 1&1's Hosted Private Network and how it should relate to setting the Static IP on the AD DC. I've created the Hosted Private Network and added the servers to the Hosted Private Network that I want to be within the forest... as soon as I add the AD DC role to the DC Server internet Access cuts out.

I'm going round and round and not finding any documented step by step examples of setting this up with 1&1 so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Windows IP Configuration

```
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : IDMS-ADDC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : foobar.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : foobar.com
```

Ethernet adapter Ethernet1:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-06-02-41
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c539:5d2c:557c:86a9%25(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419450966
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-D4-C9-AA-00-50-56-1A-23-14

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-1A-23-14
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c37:372b:29a8:3909%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 70.xx.xx.xx(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, November 12, 2015 6:05:43 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, November 13, 2015 6:05:43 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.255.255.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 70.xx.xx.xx
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302010454

   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-D4-C9-AA-00-50-56-1A-23-14

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Tunnel adapter isatap.{611C9B6D-B30A-4538-AF1A-88AAD48ED141}:

```
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4623:c945::4623:c945(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 385875968
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-D4-C9-AA-00-50-56-1A-23-14

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7B88D73C-D6EA-451F-85E0-E001058D9133}:

```
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see that example to give you an idea on how to create the VPN, it's well illustrated; 
https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw10572

nb; This example use a sonicwall & azure.

For the Internet cut off, I suspect a DNS's configuration error. Check the server DNS forwarder.

> To configure a DNS server to use forwarders using the Windows interface
>
> ```
> Open DNS Manager.
>
> In the console tree, click the applicable DNS server.
>
> Where?
>     DNS/Applicable DNS server
>
> On the Action menu, click Properties.
>
> On the Forwarders tab, under DNS domain, click a domain name.
>
> Under Selected domain's forwarder IP address list, type the IP address of a forwarder, and then click Add.
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! I misphrased the "VPN" it is actually a hosted private network... would this be handled any differently?

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs Hi, no, as your network have to talk there anyhow in both direction. The methodology can be a vpn, even if the term change. (to connect to the hosted private network, you would use a vpn or something else is what I mean). Please give us an ipconfig /all from that hosted server and one from a computer in your lan (update your question). That will give us an idea

Comment: I've added the ipconfig/all... please forgive the formatting... for some reason it didn't format right. Also note that I've set my hosted network address at: 192.168.0.0 and subnet of: 255.255.255.0

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs Thanks. The DC got 2 NIC ? One on the internet and one in the LAN as I see it ? Multi-homing a DC is a bad practice at first. I start to doubt any connection is secured to the hoster. It's a bad thing

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... We got it rolling with your help. Sorry not enough cred on ServerFalult to upvote.